# how to access to parent server from a docker

Tags: docker

I want to run a docker on a server and I expect that docker executes a shell script on the server. I understand that I can do it by "docker.sock" but I couldn't find an example of how to do it. would you mind helping me with this? I am new to docker.

The reason I chose this approach is that I have a different set of scripts for each build of my application in that docker so I want to kind of standardize my process of deployment.
[image]

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do this through `docker.sock`. Why does your deployment involve executing something on the host? How does that help you standardize the process?

Comment: I don't want two times to clone the project. there is a script which needs to run on on-prem server via octopus. then build will happen via gitlab-ci. so I was thinking to create a docker and push the necessary script for publishing that image and then from octopush run that docker on my on-prem server and that do the necessary tasks...

Comment: Mounting host's `docker.sock` as a volume in a container lets the `docker` command in the container user host's Docker, but it won't enable you to run arbitrary code on the host (at least not trivially). If you actually have to execute something on the host rather than inside the container, you can run a daemon on the host that will listen on a named pipe, then mount that pipe as a volume into a container and make the container write to it. Ideally you'd want to restrict which commands can be executed like this

Comment: @gronostaj, so basically you are saying that docker cannot communicate with the daemon. by any chance is there an example regarding the approach you proposed? I am not so expert in this area.

Comment: @gronostaj: docker api also cannot help in this senario?

Comment: _"so basically you are saying that docker cannot communicate with the daemon"_ - I'm not sure what you mean here. I've implemented a setup like what I've described a couple years ago so it's definitely possible, but unfortunately I have no documentation for how it was done.